# Matlab exp only works on the first element?

Tags: matlab, exp, elementwise-operations

I've been trying to get a simple sigmoid function to work in matlab and it seems it only works for the first element of the matrix.

my code is:

```
function g = sigmoid(z)
    g = zeros(size(z));
    g = 1/(1 + exp(-z));
end
```

Now it works fine for simple values like:

```
>>sigmoid(0)
ans = 0.5000
```

but for:
`

```
>>k = [0; 0; 0; 0; 0];
>>sigmoid(k)`
```

it's giving me:

```
ans = 0.5000 0 0 0 0
```

looking into 'exp' it says its an element-wise operation, so I am not sure where I am going wrong. Any help would be appreciated. :)

Answer (score 1):

A few issues here.

1. You don't need to pre-allocate `g` only to reassign it in the next line.
2. You need to use element-wise division `./` rather than matrix division `/`

So the correct function would be:

```
function g = sigmoid(z)
    g = 1 ./ (1 + exp(-z));
end
```